# Multiple OR conditions for a range of columns in ifelse R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

Using R, I have a dataframe:

```
ID col1 col2 col3 ... col20
1   0     0    2        0
2   3     1    0        0
3   0     0    0        1
```

I want to have a column called `cond` in which for each row, if any of the values of col1 to col3 have a value >=2, it is 1, otherwise 0. The output will be as follows:

```
ID col1 col2 col3 ... col20  cond
1   0     0    2        0      1
2   3     1    0        0      1 
3   0     0    0        1      0
```

So instead of writing multiple OR conditions, I tried writing with a single line of code:

```
df$cond <- ifelse (df[2:4] >= 2, 1, 0)
```

This returns all the values of the `cond` = 0.

I will be glad to hear about your solutions.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @maydin this is the solution:

```
df$cond <- ifelse(rowSums(df[2:4] >= 2)>=1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: `df$cond <- ifelse(rowSums(df[2:4] >= 2)>=1, 1, 0)`

Comment: @maydin this command will write 1 if all the values of col1:col3 for a subject is 1 (Which I don't want)

Comment: What do you want exactly? It returns 1 if there exists any value greater than 2 in one of the rows from col1 to col2, otherwise 0. If you want to have the same for column base, you can change it to `colSums` instead. But it does not make sense since you assign the values row base.

Comment: You should add an example what is your expected output should be.

Comment: Thanks @Vishwas, I added an example.

Comment: @AmirHusseinAbdolalizadeh The solution above gives what you expected!

Comment: Thanks @maydin, you are right! I did not see >=1 part in the condition.